# Samsung Messages/SMS - What exactly does logging into your google account do?

Tags: samsung, sms, google, android-12, google-messages

Does doing so let others know that you're texting them from a google account and it'll show your google account, or is it just a way to keep track/save your SMS messages you send?

What is the main function of having a google account used to send SMS messages? I haven't found any use for it.

Comment: Does Samsung Messages (not to be confused with [Messages by Google](https://support.google.com/messages/answer/10324785)) app asks the user to log in to Google account? I also have a Samsung phone, but I already logged-in to my Google account, so I didn't realize it.

Comment: Your SMS app is badly designed. SMS functionality doesn't need Google account, or for that matter, any web service account. Switch to a third-party SMS app (try F-Droid or Google Play Store to search them).

Answer (score 1):

If you're sending sms with an internet connection, you can tunnel your messages through a vpn for privacy concerns. Is the only "useful" function, I can think of. If, it matters. Sms through your regular mobile data is not so private.

Comment: VPN adds no privacy here. If the app uses internet to send SMS than it means it connects to a server to send the SMS to forward it to the recipient. If the app and server enforces HTTPS on both ends than SMS data would remain private between intermediaries. If HTTPS is not used between the app and the server than an intermediary can read the SMS messages including the VPN provider.

Comment: I think logging into google is solely to add pictures from google photos or something like that without changing the quality, that's it.